# NoSuchElementException in python selenium(<span>Incident</span>)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When I am trying to click the Incident tab as highlighted in Image, it gives me an error. Below is the script.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://*****.service-now.com/")
driver.switch_to.frame('gsft_main')
driver.find_element_by_id('user_name').send_keys('*****')
driver.find_element_by_id('user_password').send_keys('*****')
driver.find_element_by_id('sysverb_login').click()
Incident=driver.find_element_by_link_text('Incident')
```

This is the element I got when copied after Inspecting the page

```
<span>Incident</span>
```

This is xpath

```
//*[@id="concourse_application_dead1309c611228701e2bda7b4252474"]/a/span
```

Tried both but no success. Gives me below error.`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):    
  File "Test1.py", line 10, in <module>    
    Incident=driver.find_element_by_link_text('Incident')    
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 428, in find_element_by_link_text
    return self.find_element(by=By.LINK_TEXT, value=link_text)    
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element 'value': value})['value']    
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)    
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response    
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Incident"}
```

Answer (score 0):

`find_element_by_link_text()` and `find_element_by_partial_link_text()` works only on `<a>` tags, your element is a `<span>`. You need to use `xpath` for to locate it

```
incident = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(., "Incident")]')
```

Since you are navigated to another page you should also add some wait

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
incident = wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//span[contains(., "Incident")]')))
```

Answer (score 0):

The element with text as **Incident** is actually within a `<span>` node. Though it is within a parent `<a>` node, you won't be able to use `find_element_by_link_text()` or `find_element_by_partial_link_text()` to locate the element.

---

However, as the desired element is a dynamic element so to locate and `click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  incident = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[id^='concourse_application_dead']>a>span")))
  ```
- Using `XPATH` A:

  ```
  incident = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Incident']")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a detailed relevant discussion in:

- [Selenium “selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException” when using Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294)